# Using Boost with Team Foundation Server

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, tfs

What would be a good way to use Boost in a small team (< 10 people) and lower the time between joining the team and building the application as much as possible. I basically want a workflow like this...

1. Set up the TFS with the new person's username + password.
2. Have them log into the TFS from Visual Studio.
3. Check out the team project (which uses boost libraries) and hit build.
4. Build succeeds. Now they can get hacking.

Suggestions, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in an already-compiled Boost into a "vendor" folder, then just point all the project refs toward that folder.

Comment: "Vendor folder"?

Like, a separate team project, or what? I don't quite understand.

Comment: Just make a folder in your solution named "vendor" (or "ext" or "lib" or "herearetheboostbinaries") and check all of the Boost library in

Comment: I had a configuration like this using SVN and it didn't work well because boost has over 20 000 files. Checking for modifications (update, commit, etc.) became very slow. I'm not sure how TFS works but have this in mind. In the end we added boost as a self-extracting archive.

Comment: So do I need to do that for every solution that uses boost? Seems kinda expensive.